# Stop bing maps simplifying polygons

Tags: polygon, bing-maps, simplify

Bing maps currently simplifies each polygon shape that gets put on the map.

While that's good for most things, I need to show the full resolution polygons and I'll sort out the simplification myself.

Any ideas on how to do this, I can't seem to find a way to turn it off and finding documentation on Bing/live/VE/MS/whatever maps is a nightmare!

Any help appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently had a very similiar problem and found that setting the following (badly named) method worked.

```
VEMap.EnableShapeDisplayThreshold(false);
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964367.aspx) for all the details.